# Trying to use data from Google Form response to create Google Sheet whenever someone submits a form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

**Goal:**  Write a program in the Google Script Editor that takes the responses from a Google Form filled out by an employee of an auto repair shop, does a little math, and adds the values to a nice looking template, then saves and sends the newly created repair estimate to wherever.

I've got three files:

1. Google Form with all the questions for the employee
2. Google Sheet linked with the responses (w/ code and trigger attached)
3. Google Sheet blank template saved in Google Drive

Every time someone submit the form, I want it to:

1. Make copy of the template, rename it, save it as "Service Estimate.."
2. Get customer information, add it to sheet
3. Get the repair information, do some math, add it to the sheet
4. Save/email/print the newly created estimate to wherever

I think I've got Part #1 and Part #4 figured out, but I can't seem get the information from the form responses to go into the sheet. Dunno what I'm doing wrong. This'll be like the first program I've ever made so sorry if my code is sickening.

Right now, I'm just trying to get the basic info like the customer name into the estimate sheet. Once I get that part working, I'll worry about getting all the repairs and whatnot. Here's the code I've got in the Script Editor of the Form Response Sheet:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Get values from submitted form

var time_stamp = e.values[1];
var username = e.values[2];
var customer_name = e.values[3];
var customer_email = e.values[4];
var veh_year = e.values[5];
var veh_make = e.values[6];
var veh_model = e.values[7];
var veh_mileage = e.values[8];


var estimate_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B5lz3Xz9Jj1ifkRtT25MX0k1STFsQXlSMGk4aWdvTTFyV21RVnhIdTFrMEt2UFZ4WUY4MXM');
var basic_template_ss_id = ('1B3h440kXs1t9UiSpY5vlzoE7tdo8Z3OLernmweOo2ik');


// Get template, make a copy of it, save copy to Estimates folder

var basic_template_ss_copy_id = DocsList.getFileById(basic_template_ss_id).makeCopy('Service Estimate for ' + customer_name + ' ' + time_stamp , estimate_folder).getId();

//Get newly created blank estimate sheet

var basic_template_sheet_copy = SpeadsheetApp.openById(basic_template_ss_copy_id).getSheets()[0];


//Add basic info

var advisor_name_cell = basic_template_sheet_copy.getRange(A5);
var cust_name_cell = basic_template_sheet_copy.getRange(A7);
var year_cell = basic_template_sheet_copy.getRange(D7);
var make_cell = basic_template_sheet_copy.getRange(E7);
var model_cell = basic_template_sheet_copy.getRange(F7);



getValue(username).copyTo(advisor_name_cell);
getValue(customer_name).copyTo(cust_name_cell)
getValue(veh_year).copyTo(year_cell);
getValue(veh_make).copyTo(make_cell)
getValue(veh_model).copyTo(model_cell)

//Copy, Save, Send, Print

copyDoc.saveAndClose();
var advisor_name = getName();
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(basic_template_ss_copy_id).getAs("application/pdf");
var subject = "Service Estimate for " + customer_name;
var body = "Here's your service estimate from Midway Ford. See attached.";
MailApp.sendEmail(customer_email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
MailApp.sendEmail(username, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
}
```

[Screenshot of Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vBVp.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) in the sheet, the value should be inside quotation marks:

```
basic_template_sheet_copy.getRange("A5");
```

When you get a range in the spreadsheet you can get it's value or you can set it's value. In this case you want to use [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) to the range in the new created spreadsheet.

For example the value from username instead of having:

```
getValue(username).copyTo(advisor_name_cell);
```

you should change it to:

```
advisor_name_cell.setValue(username);
```

I think the function saveAndClose() exists only for Documents and not for Spreadsheets.

Also, the DocsList service is now deprecated as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset).

Instead of using DocsList you can use Driveapp to get the information of files in your Drive.
In this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options) you can see how to get the information from a file in Drive and use that information to attach the file as pdf in the email.

You just have to replace the id in the example for the id of the new file, which you already stored in the variable 'basic_template_ss_copy_id'.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(basic_template_ss_copy_id);
```

I hope this helps you.